# Kernel Module Upgrade with minmal downtime and no reboot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, character, linux-device-driver

I have a dynamically loaded character driver module say with Major number X which is which reading the serial port traffic and then an application is processing the serial port traffic using a /dev/ node entry with Major X.

I want to update the driver module so that new module should acquire the same major number X and start processing same serial port using the same /dev node entry with  Major X.

Unloading of old driver module is not allowed using rmmod till the new module is loaded successfully and start the takeover of the old module processing work.

There should be no reboot and upgrade to new module would be with minimal downtime of old driver module.

What should be approach to follow ?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the device driver framework and use a meta BUS, device and driver architecture to registrate your drivers making a virtual driver above your serial drivers.

your application registers with the virtual driver.

You implement a logic for the virtual driver to accept registration of new real drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, unload he mod using modprobe, add/update the mod in /lib/modules/YourKernel/, reload the mod using modprobe. Remember to compile the mod using the CURRENT version kernel header!